# Implement ROT-13 in R

Tags: string, r

I'd like a function, that when passed a string containing only letters, rotates each letter in the string through the alphabet by X characters, where X is a parameter of the function. The famous instance of this is when X=13, which is called [ROT-13](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13)

function <- ROTx(str,x) {
**??**
}

It's the kind of thing that I'd expect an R wizard could do in just a few lines, whereas I'd end up with 10 or more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rotX <- function(ch,x) 
{ #rotate each letter of a string ch by x letters thru the alphabet, as long as x<=13
  old <- paste(letters, LETTERS, collapse="", sep="")
  new <- paste(substr(old, 2*x+1, 26*2), substr(old, 1, 26), sep="")
  chartr(old, new, ch)
}
```

This fixes both of the problems I noted in my comment.

Answer (score 6):

See `?chartr` (Examples section):

```
rot <- function(ch, k = 13) {
   p0 <- function(...) paste(c(...), collapse="")
   A <- c(letters, LETTERS, " '")
   I <- seq_len(k)
   chartr(p0(A), p0(c(A[-I], A[I])), ch)
}
```

or here http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Rot-13#R:

```
rot13 <- function(x)
{
  old <- paste(letters, LETTERS, collapse="", sep="")
  new <- paste(substr(old, 27, 52), substr(old, 1, 26), sep="")
  chartr(old, new, x)
}
```

Comment: thanks, that's great- except rot('N') yields ' '- whitespace, when it should yield 'A'.  To me, this looks like an error in the chartr help, where you got the function from- assuming they were indeed intending to implement real ROT-13. This can be fixed by omitting the third string from the A definition, so the third line is instead A<- c(letter,LETTERS)     Although it also differs from standard ROT-13 by turning uppercase into lowercase sometimes and vice-versa