# Shift alphabetical characters in string

Tags: r, string, character, alphabet

Let's say I have a string:

```
s <- 'hello world zzz'
```

I want to shift the alphabetical characters up by one.

So:

- `a` becomes `b`
- `b` becomes `c`
- `c` becomes `d`
- `d` becomes `e`

and so on...

- `w` becomes `x`
- `x` becomes `y`
- `y` becomes `z`

And:

- `z` becomes `a`

---

The other condition is that if there is character that isn't in the alphabet (in this case the space), keep the characters as it is, so the space remains as a space.

---

Would all this be possible?

My desired output here would be:

```
ifmmp xpsme aaa
```

I have tried:

```
new <- c()
for (i in s) 
    {
    new <- c(new, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'[which('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' == i) + 1])
    }

print(new)
```

But it doesn't work... It outputs nothing.

Any ways of doing this?

Comment: While not exactly what you asked for, a previous question asked about [rot-13 in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4745475/3358272)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
chartr("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", "bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza", 'hello world zzz')
# [1] "ifmmp xpsme aaa"
```

(A function I've never had cause to use ...)

Comment: OMG... Why didn't I think of this!

Comment: You could also use: `chartr(letters, c(letters[-1], 'a'), 'hello world zzz')`

Comment: You should edit that in

Comment: Ummm ... I get `argument 'old' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used` (for `'new'` as well). Does it work without warning for you?

Comment: it works for me though...

Comment: Odd, I've confirmed that warns (for me) in both R-4.0.5 and R-4.1.2. Either way, glad it worked.

Comment: Well, feel free to add it into your answer :)

Comment: What version of R are you using? As I said before, it doesn't work for me in R-4.0.5 and R-4.1.2. (When I run that code in my R console, it warns (for each of `old=` and `new=`) about `has length > 1 and only the first element will be used` and returns the original string unchanged.)

Comment: R version `4.1.1`

Comment: Oh strange! Got the warning now!

Comment: Got the fix!!! `chartr(paste(letters, collapse=''), paste(c(letters[-1], 'a'), collapse=''), 'hello world zzz')` works! You can edit that in.